# Filling a text box inside of a userform from a date picker form

Tags: vba, excel, datepicker, userform

So i have a userform named NEW1 and in it i have a text box named DATE1.

In NEW1 i have a small control that opens a date picker. From this picker I need the date i select to populate the text box. This is the code i have so far.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    dateVariable = CalendarForm.GetDate( _
        SelectedDate:=Range("H34").value, _
        FirstDayOfWeek:=Monday, _
        DateFontSize:=12, _
        TodayButton:=True, _
        OkayButton:=True, _
        ShowWeekNumbers:=False, _
        BackgroundColor:=RGB(243, 249, 251), _
        HeaderColor:=RGB(147, 205, 2221), _
        HeaderFontColor:=RGB(255, 255, 255), _
        SubHeaderColor:=RGB(223, 240, 245), _
        SubHeaderFontColor:=RGB(31, 78, 120), _
        DateColor:=RGB(243, 249, 251), _
        DateFontColor:=RGB(31, 78, 120), _
        TrailingMonthFontColor:=RGB(155, 194, 230), _
        DateHoverColor:=RGB(223, 240, 245), _
        DateSelectedColor:=RGB(202, 223, 242), _
        SaturdayFontColor:=RGB(0, 176, 240), _
        SundayFontColor:=RGB(0, 176, 240), _
        TodayFontColor:=RGB(0, 176, 80))
        If dateVariable <> 0 Then Range("B5") = dateVariable

End Sub
```

so the calendar function does what it needs to, the part i need to change is the last string where it targets B5. It needs to target userform NEW1 and text box DATE1 to populate the text box DATE1.

please help!!!!

Comment: Did you try something like `Me.DATE1.Text = dateVariable` ?  You might need some formatting depending on how the value is returned from the date picker

Comment: holy night!!! You are amazing!!! one simple line... Thank you so very much!!!!!! That just save me a mountain of headache!